# How to save and export custom build steps from Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt5, qmake

I've added a new configuration with a post-build step to my project that calls a PowerShell script.
The main idea is to build my executable and compile an InnoSetup file.

The problem is that configurations are saved in the *.pro.user file, which is not to be versioned.
Is there a way to save it or to achieve a similar result with qmake and the *.pro file?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend not defining your post-build step that way. I would add it to your .pro file using `QMAKE_POST_LINK`.

Here's an example that copies some extra files to the destination directory:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK = $$QMAKE_COPY $$PWD/some/files $$DESTDIR
```

Comment: Interesting, but can I run my script or just commands provided by qmake?  
An alternative approach I was thinking of is to make an umbrella project with the subdirs template with the only goal of running my script

Comment: Yes, you can run any command. A subdirs project seems overkill for this, in my opinion.

Comment: If you want to improve my edit, please do, but with this addition I think your answer is complete